# Does syncing iPhone with change playlist order?

Tags: ios, itunes

I synced a lot of songs from my Mac to iPhone. Then I reordered the playlists on the iPhone to my liking. If I sync it back to the Mac, would the order be lost ? If yes, any ways around it ?

Comment: What are you trying to sync back, the songs or the playlist?  If the songs, nothing should change.  If the playlist, the new order should be used.

Comment: I am trying to sync back the playlist that I reordered on my iPhone. Was wondering if the original playlist order on Mac would overwrite the iPhones playlist order.